# How to get email and phone number from Apple Pay using Swift

Tags: swift, applepay

I'm able to successfully retrieve all data from Apple Pay including encrypted payment data, first name, last name, and billing address. I cannot, however, seems to figure out how to retrieve the **phone number** and **email address** from the "contact" section displayed during Apple Pay checkout. I need to retrieve these values so I can submit them to my downstream payment provider. Please help:

```
extension ViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {

    /* USER HAS AUTHORIZED PAYMENT */
    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment!, completion: ((PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)!) {

        //Declare a dictionary of request parameters
        var parameters = Dictionary<String, String>()

        //Get Encrypted Payment Data from AP
        parameters["encryptedPayment_data"] = payment.token.paymentData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)

        let billingAddress: ABRecord = payment.billingAddress

        parameters["billTo_firstName"] = ABRecordCopyValue(billingAddress, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String
        parameters["billTo_lastName"] = ABRecordCopyValue(billingAddress, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String

        //Extract billing address from ABRecord format and assign accordingly
        let addressProperty: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(billingAddress, kABPersonAddressProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef

        if let dict: NSDictionary = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressProperty, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? NSDictionary {
            parameters["billTo_street1"] = dict[String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey)] as? String
            parameters["billTo_city"] = dict[String(kABPersonAddressCityKey)] as? String
            parameters["billTo_state"] = dict[String(kABPersonAddressStateKey)] as? String
            parameters["billTo_postalCode"] = dict[String(kABPersonAddressZIPKey)] as? String
            parameters["billTo_country"] = dict[String(kABPersonAddressCountryKey)] as? String //"United States"
        }

        //Can't figure out how to obtain these from Apple Pay!
        parameters["billTo_email"] = "null@sample.com"
        parameters["billTo_phoneNumber"] = "5555555555"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
let emails: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(billingAddress, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
  if ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0 {
    let email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0).takeRetainedValue() as String
    NSLog(email)  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however, the first line of code results in "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)". I interpret this to mean kABPersonEmailProperty is nil within payment.billingAddress returned from Apple Pay. Where else could the email and phone possibly be exposed?

Comment: Forgot to mention I am setting billing and shipping address to required, and they DO appear during the AP checkout process: request.requiredBillingAddressFields = PKAddressField.All;request.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressField.All;

Comment: The plot thickens... I can obtain email using your code from payment.shippingAddress but payment.billingAddress returns nil. I wonder if Apple intentionally holds this back?

Comment: There's only one place in the Apple Pay payment sheet to enter email and phone information, and they are returned under `shippingAddress`, not `billingAddress`.

Comment: Can anyone convert this to Objective C please.

Comment: @Jeff You were able to get the email address?